# Printing on console screen witout printf() in c

Tags: c

The code given in my textbook of c programming as

```
#define DATATYPE char far*   
main()
{
  DATATYPE s;
   s = 0xb8000000;
  *s = 'A'; 
   getch(); 
}
```

by executing this code I'm getting A printed on top left corner of screen. In order to justify it is written in book that 0xb8000000 is the address that refer to top-left position of screen and is 32-bit address which is called far pointer.
But the idea is not clear about it so can anybody justify it me more clearly. Thank you.

Comment: This will be a good read for you: https://littleosbook.github.io/#the-framebuffer (the whole book is worthwhile)

Comment: Your textbook is outdated garbage.

Comment: Very old example. Very old `main`.

Comment: What are the odds of someone finding that old textbook *and* having an old enough computer that the old-school framebuffer-writing code actually works? (Or is -- horrors! -- Windows still doggedly implementing a pseudo-framebuffer at 0xb8000000 for the benefit of old code that's still using it?)